# Apply the distinct on 2 fields and also fetch the unique data for each columns

Tags: sql, oracle

According to some weird requirement, i need to select the record where all the output values in both the columns should be unique.

Input looks like this:

```
col1   col2
1       x
1       y
2       x
2       y
3       x
3       y
3       z
```

Expected Output is:

```
col1  col2
1     x
2     y
3     z
```

or

```
col1  col2
1     y
2     x
3     z
```

I tried applying the distinct on 2 fields but that returns all the records as overall they are distinct on both the fields. What we want to do is that if any value is present in the col1, then it cannot be repeated in the col2.

Please let  me know if this is even possible and if yes, how to go about it.

Comment: There are many more columns present in the table but they are not related to this so have ignored them for now.
Regarding what i have tried:
I tried using the min, max function with group by to see if i can identify the unique rows but it didnt work.
Also, just to make the reuirement more clear here is an another example
Input:
col1 col2
1 x
1 y
2 x

Output:
col1 col2
1 x

Comment: Not sure that this is even possible as you want indeterministic behaviour

Comment: Do you need a single SQL statement or just any solution, also including PLSQL?

Comment: What's the actual 'order' here?  Why isn't `2 x` an option for that last example?

Comment: Because x was already select for 1... He want's every value to appear only once, no matter in which combination

Comment: I understand that its a little bit awkard and difficult, however i would appreciate even if this can be done through the PLSQL block.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: every time i try ,i end up with this `1-x,1-y 3-z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great problem!  Armunin has picked up on the deeper structural issue here, this is a recursive enumerable problem description and can only be resolved with a recursive solution - base relational operators (join/union/etc) are not going to get you there.  As Armunin cited, one approach is to bring out the PL/SQL, and though I haven't checked it in detail, I'd assume the PL/SQL code will work just fine.  However, Oracle is kind enough to support recursive SQL, through which we can build the solution in just SQL:

-- Note - this SQL will generate *every* solution - you will need to filter for SOLUTION_NUMBER=1 at the end

```
with t as (
select 1 col1, 'x' col2 from dual union all
select 1 col1, 'y' col2 from dual union all
select 2 col1, 'x' col2 from dual union all
select 2 col1, 'y' col2 from dual union all
select 3 col1, 'x' col2 from dual union all
select 3 col1, 'y' col2 from dual union all
select 3 col1, 'z' col2 from dual
), 
t0 as 
    (select t.*, 
            row_number() over (order by col1) id, 
            dense_rank() over (order by col2) c2_rnk 
     from t),
-- recursive step...
t1 (c2_rnk,ids, str) as
    (-- base row
     select c2_rnk, '('||id||')' ids, '('||col1||')' str 
     from   t0 
     where  c2_rnk=1
     union all
     -- induction
     select t0.c2_rnk, ids||'('||t0.id||')' ids, str||','||'('||t0.col1||')' 
     from   t1, t0 
     where  t0.c2_rnk = t1.c2_rnk+1 
            and instr(t1.str,'('||t0.col1||')') =0
    ),
t2 as 
    (select t1.*, 
            rownum solution_number 
     from   t1 
     where  c2_rnk = (select max(c2_rnk) from t1)
    )
select  solution_number, col1, col2 
from    t0, t2 
where   instr(t2.ids,'('||t0.id||')') <> 0
order by 1,2,3


SOLUTION_NUMBER       COL1    COL2 
1                     1       x    
1                     2       y    
1                     3       z    
2                     1       y    
2                     2       x    
2                     3       z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a full outer join to merge two numbered lists together:

```
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM  ( SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1 ) col1_num
        FROM   your_table
        GROUP BY col1 )
  FULL JOIN 
      ( SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col2 ) col2_num
        FROM   your_table
        GROUP BY col2 )
  ON  col1_num = col2_num
```

Change ORDER BY if you require a different order and use ORDER BY NULL if you're happy to let Oracle decide.

Comment: as OP need if col1 col2 1 x 1 y 2 x 1 xx o/p: col1 col2 1 x

Comment: It's not working for all input, as shown [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/851f6/3). You get 3 x as output although it is not a viable solution. Not sure though whether thats to complex input for OPs question

Comment: @KevanGelling Yeah I know, that were just some changes I did for testing. Not sure why they are still in there. The FULL Join doesn't change anything. It's the ORDERing that mixes up the results as you compare the row_numbers. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/851f6/9) for Comparison with `FULL JOIN` and `ORDER BY NULL`. This time gives 2 x as a viable solution.

Comment: @Armunin - You can try "ORDER BY MIN(col1), col2" but I think Ramblin'Man needs to be clearer with the required order

Comment: @KevanGelling I am not sure he will get his desired outcome as the behaviour he asked for is indeterministic, so he will get a different outcome everytime he changes the `ORDER BY` of any suggested solution so far. And depending on his inputdata he will miss the one or the other dataset in his output.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the result if another row of 
`col1` value as 1 and `col2` value as `xx` ?

A single row is better in this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(col1) FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Except I'm pretty sure the OP wants this as two columns.

Comment: If any value is already present in the o/p then they should be filtered.
Even then that record should not be selected as 1 is already selected in the 1st record.
i/p:
col1 col2
1 x
1 y
2 x
1 xx

o/p:
col1 col2
1 x

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is something like this:

```
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE global TEMPORARY TABLE tmp(col1 NUMBER, col2 VARCHAR2(50))';
end;
/
DECLARE
    cur_print sys_refcursor;
    col1 NUMBER;
    col2 VARCHAR(50);
    CURSOR cur_dist
    IS
        SELECT DISTINCT
            col1
        FROM
            ttable;
    filtered sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN cur_dist
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO tmp
        SELECT
            col1,
            col2
        FROM
            ttable t1
        WHERE
            t1.col1         = rec.col1
        AND t1.col2 NOT IN
            (
                SELECT
                    tmp.col2
                FROM
                    tmp
            )
        AND t1.col1 NOT IN
            (
                SELECT
                    tmp.col1
                FROM
                    tmp
            )
        AND ROWNUM = 1;
    END LOOP;

    FOR rec in (select col1, col2 from tmp) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col1: ' || rec.col1 || '|| col2: ' || rec.col2);
    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tmp';
END;
/
```

May still need some refining, I am especially not happy with the `ROWNUM = 1` part.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d81c6/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( col1, col2 ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'y' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'y' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'x' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'y' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'z' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH c1 AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT
          col1,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rank
  FROM    tbl
),
c2 AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT
          col2,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS rank
  FROM    tbl
)
SELECT c1.col1,
       c2.col2
FROM   c1
       FULL OUTER JOIN c2
       ON ( c1.rank = c2.rank)
ORDER BY COALESCE( c1.rank, c2.rank)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d81c6/5/0)**:

```
| COL1 |   COL2 |
|------|--------|
|    1 |      x |
|    2 |      y |
|    3 |      z |
|    4 | (null) |
```

And to address the additional requirement:

> What we want to do is that if any value is present in the col1, then it cannot be repeated in the col2.

**Query 2**:

```
WITH c1 AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT
          col1,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rank
  FROM    tbl
),
c2 AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT
          col2,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS rank
  FROM    tbl
  WHERE   col2 NOT IN ( SELECT TO_CHAR( col1 ) FROM c1 )
)
SELECT c1.col1,
       c2.col2
FROM   c1
       FULL OUTER JOIN c2
       ON ( c1.rank = c2.rank)
ORDER BY COALESCE( c1.rank, c2.rank)
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking pain to write the sqls. 
Regarding your question, if value present in the col2 cannot be repeated then we can filter that record and they should not be selected in the select query.

Comment: Query 1 will select the distinct items in `col1` and all the distinct items in `col2`; Query 2 further restricts this such that all the distinct items from both `col1` and `col2` are selected and if there is an item in both `col1` and `col2` then it will only appear in `col1`.